# Blurred Step + multi-shifting

Tags: dnd-4e, battlemind

If a baddie next to me shifts x, and I can shift x with blurred step, what is the interaction like? Does he declare his shift one square at a time, so that I can just follow the first shift (and then I've expended the once/turn use) or does he have to declare the final destination of the shift when he starts?

(Naturally, this effects Harrying Step as well.)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As a Free action (post-errata), Blurred Step triggers after the action that triggered it is resolved.**

Some definitions to start with:

[Blurred Step](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=10439)

> Free Action      Personal
>
> Trigger: An adjacent enemy marked by you shifts
>
> Effect: You shift 1 square.
>
> Special: You can use this power only once per turn.

[Free Action] as reaction:

> I'm playing a battlemind. If an adjacent enemy that I have marked attempts to shift to another square adjacent to me, can I use blurred step to shift to that square and prevent the enemy from entering it?
>
> No. The free action granted by blurred step occurs after the action that triggers it.

Therefore, given that it is triggered after the *action* and not the *movement* the enemy moves, and then you move to follow, which preserves both the spirit and the wording of the rules.